# Catching notifications on android

Tags: java, android, notifications

I need to do a simple app for android.

This application must to do these two things:

- Catch any incoming notification.
- See what is the "Target Application" of this notification.

The purpose is to light a Lamp with a customized color for each notification.

Examples: 
New Facebook Notification => Lamp turn blue.
New Gmail Notification => Lamp turn red.

So the app need only to see if there is a new notification and wich is the Target App.

Is possible to catch the notifications of any application on the phone? or android rescrict such possibility?

If yes, anyone can share with me a little snippet?
If not, anyone can suggest me any alternative solution?

Thank you.

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: Notifications go through the NotificationManager, they are not broadcast.  So, there is no way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

And this is a *feature*. If you could catch notifications from other apps, you could conceivably get around permissions restrictions.

As an additional note, I am not sure that colored LEDs are part of the CDD, so the feature would not be available to all users.